# Error: package android:support.v4.#### does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin, android-support-library

I want to add fragments to my application and I installed the `xamarin.android.support.v4` and other required but it gives an error

> error: package `android:support.v4.view` or `app` or `content` etc. does not exist.

I have tried on a blank project with the same results.

I am using Android 7.0 and the latest support library.

Comment: `android.app.Fragment` doesn't require the support library, by the way

Comment: Yeah but what about other features that are from the support library?

Comment: You just said you wanted to add Fragments :)

Comment: For now,i want to also add RecyclerView and CardView

Comment: I don't know enough about Xamarin, but you need this library for sure. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/25.0.1-rc1

Comment: Installed it and the problem still persists.Dont know if it's me the problem or xamarin.

Comment: Are you able to install other libraries? The only other C# one I can think of would be Newtonsoft / JSON

Comment: Yep.As a matter of fact i am using it in my application just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For now,i want to also add RecyclerView and CardView

To use these two controls, you need to install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView` package and `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView` in your project. When you install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView` package using Nuget, the `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` package will automatically be installed.

And you can use `RecyclerView` like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

And so is the `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:text="Caption"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You can refer to the official document [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) of Xamarin for using and customizing `RecyclerView` in Xamarin.Android applications.

If there is still problem, could you please provide a minimal reproducible demo, so can we continue to investigate this issue.

Comment: I updated Xamarin and it seemed to have fixed the issue.If it happens again i will notify you!